# How to load dll in C++

Tags: c++, dll

I would like to load Dll in my c++ project, but the problem is I do not have the source code of the Dll that I was using. So I can't modify anything in the dll e.g. add export def file, or export c method for the dll. Any solution for this situation ?

Have tried load library function, and it was successful load the Dll.

How to call the function within the dll without def file, or export c method ?

Comment: Assuming you are on a Windows system (since you mention DLL) you should read about [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and related function.

Comment: Agree. Also if you do not know the functions exported by this DLL, you can download some tool to see the export list (I think DepencencyWalker is the best)

Comment: You can use this Dependency Walker [link](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), PE explorer,etc. to find the exported function. After you find the exported function use GetProcAddress function to load the function.

Comment: Hi all, can I export the dll without .def file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know what the DLL provides to you. You should get a header files with the definitions of structures (if any) and the function prototype(s) including the calling conventions.

You can get the list of exported functions with `dumpbin /exports TheDll.dll`. You should further check the CPU it is made for with the `dumpbin` command. This avoids a 32/64 bit trouble.

You can load any compatible DLL (32/64) with the `LoadLibrary` API function. Include the appropriate header to get the prototype.

You get a pointer to an exported function with the `GetProcAddress` function. If you have the function signature, you can use this pointer to call the function.

Comment: thanks harper, have tried dumpbin in visual studio command prompt, and list out undecorated functions name and paste into GetProcAddress function, it works.